# Angular 2 code for multiple filters

Tags: angular

I am new to angular js. I am trying to achieve same functionality with angular 2 as [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wYfs4/689/).

The html I used in angular 1 is below:

```
Basically i have an array like:
[
    {name: 'Wine A', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine B', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine C', category: 'white'},
    {name: 'Wine D', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine E', category: 'red'},
    {name: 'Wine F', category: 'white'},
    {name: 'Wine G', category: 'champagne'},
    {name: 'Wine H', category: 'champagne'}    
  ];
```

The array can have more than 2 attributes. I want checkbox filters to be generated for each of the attributes as in js fiddle example I gave.

I have spent two days but unable to do same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular2 way of iterating over an array is with the `ngFor` directive

```
<div *ngFor="let wine of wineArray" >
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="wine.selected">
    <label>{{ wine.name }}</label>
</div>
```

We bind the checkbox selection to the original array using `ngModel`

More information on `ngFor` & `ngModel` is available in the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor)

If you are more familiar with Angular1, there is also a [useful conversion guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html) for mapping techniques from ng1 to ng2

Comment: Thanks @Christopher